# Laravel Lumen Return 500 Error When Sending Notification

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, lumen

I tried to send a verification email in Laravel/Lumen using this piece of code.

```
 public function sendEmailVerificationNotification() {
        try {
          $this->notify(new VerifyEmail);
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
          print_r($e->getMessage());
        }
      }
```

The problem is I always get error 500. The cause of the error seems to be `$this->notify()` function because when I comment that line, the service runs perfectly. I put the try-catch block to find out the reason of the failure but I got nothing. Instead of getting the cause, I only get the error 500 display.
[image: Error 500]

I am confused because I cannot find the root cause. Do any of you have experienced the same thing? Or maybe you can suggest to me a way to debug it so that I can get the information about the root cause.

Comment: Check whether you have APP_DEBUG set to true in your .env file

Comment: Thank you, I missed that configuration. I can get the error cause now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all I guess your `.env` file has `APP_DEBUG` set to `false`. In order to get the actual error stack setting that it true will help you a lot. Use `APP_DEBUG = false` in production servers and apps not in your development.

Coming back to the point, I don't know if its valid but sometimes I faced this situation due to the reason that I have configured all my queued jobs to be pushed to `Redis` and sometimes in my local machine I forget to turn `Redis` service ON.

If this is applicable to you also please check that.

**Note**: This may not be applicable to you.